# use regular expression to prase specified protocol

Tags: java, regex

My server receive a message like `#1037szdx001A8911*`,now I need to get `szdx001` called `sid`
The length of `sid` is decided by the character `7`. The length will be 8 or 9 ．
It is easy to use `String.substring()` to get the length first. Then I will get the `sid` according to the length.

But Now I try to use regular expression.Here is my pattern． 
`#(\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d)(\\w{7})(\\w)(\\d{4})*`

My Problem is that how I can replace 7 with the following group in java grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by "The length of sid is decided by the character 7"? Your `szdx001` String is 7 characters long but then you state it's `8` or `9`. Although, where is the "character 7" in your input? Is it the character at index 4? Quite unclear...

Comment: I am sorry that I don't say clearly.the character 7 is at index 4.The character in index 4 may be 8 or 9. Then I get the substring of the protocol which length of the substring is the value of index 4.

Comment: Without the information on why only `7` should be used to interpret the length of the string (instead of `37` or `1037`), we can't give you any reasonable answer on how to parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the regular expression that you provided, it looks like the input string normally splits up into these fields:

```
# 1 03 7 szdx001 A 8911 *
```

and the 5th field (szdx...) is the only field that is variable in size? If that's correct, then you don't need to know its size to parse the string into fields:

```
#(\d)(\d{2})(\d)(\w+)(\w)(\d{4})*
```

The above regular expression will parse the first four fields and the last fields as fixed-size. The variable-sized field will get whatever text lies between the 4th and 6th fields. You would have to check separately that the fifth field is the correct length. [*Note* I've removed the doubled backslashes here; we're just talking about the regular expression, not the correct way to specify backslashes in a string constant.]

A slightly more restrictive form of the above is:

```
#(\d)(\d{2})(\d)(\w{7,9})(\w)(\d{4})*
```

This limits the fifth field to between 7 and 9 characters.

If you must parse the string using *only* a regular expression, and you can't validate the length of the fifth field separately, then you could do something like this:

```
#(\d)(\d{2})(?:7(\w{7})|8(\w{8})|9(\w{9}))(\w)(\d{4})*
```

The important part is `(?:7(\w{7})|8(\w{8})|9(\w{9}))`. This is a non-capturing group containing three alternatives: '7' followed by a 7-character string, or '8' followed by an 8-character string, or '9' followed by a 9-character string. Note that the numbers of each capture group will change here; the 7-, 8-, and 9-character strings are each in different capture groups, so your code will have to examine all three.